# cache_counter getting out of sync on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I assume there's some kind of race condition, although the code executes in the save transaction, so I'm not quite sure how these numbers could be getting out of sync.

All cache_counters on the site have at least a few of these errors.

Answer (score 0):

Make a cron job to reset them.